# Regular expression tracer

Tags: regex

I am looking for free alternative for [Regex Match Tracer (v2.0)](http://www.regexlab.com/en/mtracer/). There are many regular expression checkers, but they don't show matches results.
I need to check regexp and view all matches. It can by in any language (PHP, JavaScript, or a Windows `.exe`...). Do you know something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could paste here a very long list, bu personally I use [rubular](http://www.rubular.com) ([here](http://www.rubular.com/r/5xU9HrHIgX) and [here](http://www.rubular.com/r/7Q3FdwAdEp) are examples of it showing matches); because of:

- readability, ease of use and nice graphics
- "permalink" feature
- "show invisibles" feature

Answer (score 3):

There are plenty of online tools.

Here are some:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

http://regexpal.com/

http://myregexp.com/

http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/

Comment: http://regexr.com/ is just a nicer URL for http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Answer (score 0):

It's not difficult to test what matches and submatches result from a regex in scripting languages like Perl/Python/Ruby.  And not much harder to wrap that into a script.